# Swagger error in implementation webdav methods

Tags: asp.net-core, swagger, swagger-ui, webdav, http-method

Swagger generate error:

**An unhandled exception has occurred while executing the request.
System.Collections.Generic.KeyNotFoundException: The given key 'PROPFIND' was not present in the dictionary.**

My implementation this method:

```
[AcceptVerbs("PROPFIND")]
[Route("{drive}")]
public async Task<ActionResult> Propfind(string drive)
```

Postman success send this method, but swagger UI not working. How fix this ?

Comment: One of resolve is marked api attribute [ApiExplorerSettings(IgnoreApi = true)]. Swagger ignored this methods, but no possible tesing them across Swagger.

Comment: Have you found a working solution?